# Magento2 : How to migrate wordpress website into magento website

Tags: magento2

How to migrate wordpress made site all data  in magneto2? if any one know reply me

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url, but I haven't come across a readymade script like that.

Performing migration manually will be safe and error free as the one mentioned here

http://blog.contus.com/migrate-from-woocommerce-to-a-magento-platform

I hope its very helpful to you.

Comment: can you specific plugin name sent for only wordpress to magento2 migration

Comment: check this one - https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/6684-woocommerce-to-magento-migration